# Does display.getSize() include the black bar at the bottom of some devices?

Tags: android

In my Android app, I need to get the height and width of the view area in the app. I'm using the following code to get that information:

```
Display display = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
Point size = new Point();
display.getSize(size);
int width = size.x;
int height = size.y;
```

However, I noticed that when I run the app in the emulator, the height variable also includes the black bar with the back, home and menu buttons. When I run it on my phone, I get a true value because my buttons are on the physical phone, not the screen. I don't have an Android device with the screen buttons to test with.

I'm curious, will my code include the height of the black bar? I would assume that the Android OS would not include the section taken up by that black bar as a usable part of the screen, but I'm not sure.

Is there some alternate way that I could get the height and width of the main relative layout when it's set as match_parent in the XML? This would probably be the better method, but I tried giving the layout an ID and targeting it in the Java code to get the size, but it crashed the app.

Any information or help would be very much appreciated.